# How to remove title of PDF inside iframe that automatically generated by browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe

I'm using `iframe` to view PDF file from `base64` string. When it is rendered successfully, the browser automatically set a title for it. I've tried to remove it by CSS but it's not working.
Is there anyway to hide or remove it? Thank you guys!

Here is my sample code:

**app.component.html**

```
<iframe #ManualFrame [src]=" url | safe: 'resourceUrl'"  width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 let base64String = 'JVBERi0xLjUNCjQgMCBvYmoNCjw8L...'
 this.url = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64String;
```

Comment: Is this using angular?

Comment: yes, I'm using Angular 6 @PaulRooney